# React built with concurrently.js not finding build command [react-scripts: command not found]

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm attempting to deploy a react app that uses express and concurrently on on Elastic Beanstalk however I get an error that it cannot find react-scripts command. I've double checked that react-scripts is a dependency in the json (its auto generated by react) so I'm not quite sure why its still unable to find it.

Below is the log

```
-------------------------------------
/var/log/nodejs/nodejs.log
-------------------------------------
[0] 
[0] > project-deztructicus@0.1.0 server-live /var/app/current
[0] > node server.js
[0] 
[0] Server started on port 5000
[1] 
[1] > client@0.1.0 start /var/app/current/client
[1] > react-scripts start
[1] 
[1] sh: react-scripts: command not found
[1] npm ERR! file sh
[1] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
[1] npm ERR! errno ENOENT
[1] npm ERR! syscall spawn
[1] npm ERR! client@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
[1] npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
[1] npm ERR! 
[1] npm ERR! Failed at the client@0.1.0 start script.
[1] npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
[1] npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?
[1] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
[1] npm ERR! errno 1
[1] npm ERR! project-deztructicus@0.1.0 client: `npm start --prefix client`
[1] npm ERR! Exit status 1
[1] npm ERR! 
[1] npm ERR! Failed at the project-deztructicus@0.1.0 client script.
[1] npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
[1] npm run client exited with code 1
```

Many thanks in advance! :-)

Comment: I set the package.json to require node 12+ and npmp 6+ yet still get this same error. I thought it's because it needs react-scripts installed globally, but you got it working without doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a `create-react-app` issue, is a npm one. 
Check this link https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17379

Comment: EBS by default uses an old version of NPM and Node. Updating npm and node fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE:** It seems this is just an inconsistency between `yarn` and `npm`
https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17379#issuecomment-358434577

<s>You can try to remove `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` or `yarn.lock`

And execute `npm install` again.</s>

Or you can downgrade `npm` to `4.6.1` that does not have the issue

```
npm -g i npm@4.6.1
```